# Do these two php functions produce the same result?

Tags: php, isset

I am currently working my way through a PHP course and am curious as to if these two functions produce the same result, is one more efficient then the other? If so please explain, thank you.

```
public function is_logged_in(){
    if ($_SESSION['user_id'] == true){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}



public function is_logged_in(){
    if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
 }
```

Comment: why is `$_SESSION['user_id']` a boolean?

Comment: partly this depends on error reporting levels.
first function will throw a notice error if user_id is not set.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$_SESSION['user_id']` is a typical numeric ID and is not equal to 0, then yes. The only scenario that this is not the same is when `$_SESSION['user_id']` is literally `false`, `0` or `''`(empty string).

Comment: $_SESSION['user_id']='';

Answer (score 0):

No they are not the same, you can test this

```
<?php
$falseVar = false;
var_dump(isset($falseVar));
```

this will output **true** becuase a variable contains false **is set**.

so if your `$_SESSION['user_id']` tested with `isset`, it will return true whether `$_SESSION['user_id']` is true or false

I think you need to use [`!empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) instead of `isset()`

Answer (score 0):

it depends on what $_SESSION['user_id'] is.

isset is used to determine a value is not null. It means isset will return false while the $_SESSION['user_id'] is null.

but '$_SESSION['user_id'] == true' works more complicated.

> a value will be automatically converted if an operator, function or control structure requires a boolean argument.

therefore, '$_SESSION['user_id'] == true' is true or false depends on  what $_SESSION['user_id'] will be converted to.

When converting to boolean, the following values are considered FALSE:

- the boolean FALSE itself
- the integer 0 (zero)
- the float 0.0 (zero)
- the empty string, and the string "0"
- an array with zero elements
- the special type NULL (including unset variables)
- SimpleXML objects created from empty tags

[PHP Booleans](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php)